# Writing ASCII symbols to video memory in assembly with TASM on 8086

Tags: memory, video, assembly, x86-16, tasm

I need to write a program for writing ASCII symbols to the video memory.

```
.model tiny
.stack
.data
.code
main: 

mov ax, 0b800h
mov ds, ax

mov aL, 'x'
mov es, bx
mov es:[1], aL

mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

end main
```

This code is inert as of yet; it compiles, runs and then exits without printing anything.
I think i'm missing a line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing a string without OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462807/printing-a-string-without-os)

Comment: You set `ds` to `0b800h`, and `es` to undefined value or at least not `0b800h` (`bx`). And then you use `es` to address video memory, which obviously fails.

Comment: brilliant, that was stupid of me. however I am still unable to print a character in this manner, and the program behaves as before.

Comment: In assembly level (at least in x86) string is not a datatype, it's only an abstraction in the programmer's head. You can call the data "ASCII symbols" or "string", in assembly level it's all the same: some values stored in some memory addresses, that's all.

Comment: Good to know, but I still don't see what is missing here exactly. So far I've only been able to print strings consecutively I haven't been able to write to vid. memory.

Comment: You have invalid offset for the ASCII code (`es:[1]`) (odd offsets are for colors and attributes) and you don't define the the color (well, your color & attribute byte is `0x78`, that is `x`). See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462807/printing-a-string-without-os/15463548#15463548 .

Comment: how do I define the color?

Comment: The top 4 bits specify the background color and the low 4 bits specify the text color (or the other way around). Try using 20h. AFAIR, that's black text on green.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, could you show me in context?

Comment: @user - Each position on the screen is made up of two bytes, one holds the character code and the other holds the color. If you don't set both, you might end up with a black character on a black background. Pretty hard to read!

Comment: what kind of color code goes into es[n] to produce a text and bg color?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to write to the video memory, set ES to 0b800h
Specify the place (Offset), on the screen where you want to write. Set DI to (row*(max. rows (80))+col)*2  (ROW and COL are null-based). For example to write to the third char in the 10th line use "mov di, (2*80+9)*2"
Specify the colors in AH. Set AH to (backgroundcolor*16+foregroundcolor) for example to write light gray (7) letters on a black (0) background use "mov ah, 7"
Use the STOSW instruction instead of "mov es:[adress]", al. This way you can dynamically write to different places on the screen.